# Visual Studio 2019: Post-build event not firing when build occurs as a result of hitting the "run" button

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, post-build-event

All of our projects have post-build events that zip the build output up and put the zip file in another folder.

When building via MSBuild (on the command line) or via any of the "build" options within the IDE (build all, build project, rebuild, etc.), the post-build events fire as they should and all is well.  However, if I forget to explicitly build before hitting run, the build occurs, but the post-build event does not fire.

This has been seen by several developers on our team, and is the same for all projects.  It appears to be a "feature" of Visual Studio.  Does anyone know why it works this way, and if there's any way to force it to run the post-build events after a build that occurs as a result of hitting the "run" button?

Note that this has nothing to do with the projects being up-to-date, or the "when to run" settings on the post-build events.  There is no question about it: if I change code, and press the "run" button, it will perform a build and output the build results to the bin/Debug folder, but it will not run the post-build event.  On the other hand, if I first hit the "build" button, it does run the post-build event.  Why?

Comment: Just guessing here, but have you tried unchecking the "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" box (Options -> Project & Solutions -> Build & Run)?

Comment: Holy crap!  That was it!  Thank you!!!  I hadn't known about that option!  Now I don't have to worry about this anymore!